# Added SLI, startx yielding blank screen

Tags: arch-linux, x11

[Xorg.0.log pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8Vt8gwuK)

Installed watercooling loop and my windows dual boot is fine, however Arch Linux x server won't start.

When I run startx:

1. Monitor will flicker for a moment, monitor will show display port like it reconnected.
2. The screen will be black/unresponsive.

Any tips on parsing this log to find out whats up? I've already ran yaourt -Syu. I use i3wm. The GPUs are Titan X Pascals.

EDIT: I've tried installing the missing modules. When I run X server no log is produced (it writes an empty Xorg.0.log file), when I run `Xorg -configure` I get a `Segmentation fault at address 0x50`.

EDIT2: By temporarily moving in `/etc/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` the `10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf`, I get the error `Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices` in the xorg log (among other things).

Comment: Congratulations for solving your problem! Please post your solution as an answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I've installed the missing modules. When I run X server no log is produced (it writes an empty Xorg.0.log file), when I run Xorg -configure I get a Segmentation fault at address 0x50.
2. I then temporarily moved aside in /etc/share/X11/xorg.conf.d the 10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf, I get the error

> Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices in the xorg log (among other things).

3. I ran `nvidia-xconfig` and installed and then
4. I ran `systemctl enable acpdi`

All four steps were required.